# Why can I not use the "superiors" package with any options?

Tags: fonts, packages, superscripts, package-options

I am trying to compile the following document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[supstfm=libertinesups,supscaled=1.2,raised=-.13em]{superiors}
\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```

The second line of code is taken from the package documentation (beginning of page 2, see here: https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/fonts/superiors/doc/superiors-doc.pdf).
I am presented with the error:

```
Unknown option `supstfm=libertinesups' for package `superiors'.
Unknown option `supscaled=1.2' for package `superiors'.
Unknown option `raised=-.13em' for package `superiors'.
```

Why can I not use the "superiors" package with any options?

Comment: before that error the package does warn you `Cannot load superiors with any KOMA class or package.` So you can not use it with `scrartcl`

Comment: Starting 2024, the package is compatible with KOMA script. Note that the parameter `supstfm` changed to `supsfam`: `supstfm=libertinesups` to `supsfam=LibertinusSerif-Sup`.

Answer (score 1):

you could fool the test in the package. As it overwrites the definition of the footnote mark you perhaps will loose footnote features of the KOMA classes. So test if is works.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:cc {ORIver@scrextend.sty} {ver@scrextend.sty}
\let\ORIKOMAClassName\KOMAClassName
\cs_undefine:N\KOMAClassName
\cs_undefine:c{ver@scrextend.sty}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage[supstfm=libertinesups,supscaled=1.2,raised=-.13em]{superiors}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:cc  {ver@scrextend.sty}{ORIver@scrextend.sty}
\let\KOMAClassName\ORIKOMAClassName
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
a\footnote{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that superiors does not work with scrartcl. I now just switched to article and it works fine, so I did not need the workaround suggested by you. (Seems it also would have worked, though.)

Comment: well I wouldn't drop scrartcl only to get superiors. scrartcl has a lot more options than article.